# Netbeans Tomcat to Glassfish

Tags: glassfish

I have an app that works on Netbeans 8 and Tomcat 8. I tried running on Glassfish 4 and got error on server startup :

```
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL Pattern: [{0}]
at org.glassfish.web.deployment.node.FilterMappingNode.setElementValue(FilterMappingNode.java:143)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.SaxParserHandler.endElement(SaxParserHandler.java:583)
```

I'm using SSI Filter in web.xml :

```
<filter>
<filter-name>ssi</filter-name>
<filter-class>
      org.apache.catalina.ssi.SSIFilter
    </filter-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>contentType</param-name>
  <param-value>text/html</param-value>
</init-param>
<!--    <init-param>
  <param-name>debug</param-name>
  <param-value>0</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>expires</param-name>
  <param-value>666</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>isVirtualWebappRelative</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
-->
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>ssi</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Are there any issues using SSi Filter in Glassfish? I note that all the docs use SSI Servlet in their examples.I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On looking at "Invalid URL Pattern:" errors in general for glassfish, I came across a number of issues where it doesn't like  tags that don't start with a '/'

So, I changed

```
<url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
```

to

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

and it worked. More importantly, Tomcat accepts this format as well.